# Image rotation and fading across the entire screen

Tags: ios, animation, uiimage

My problem is I have an image and I'm able to move it top down. But what I want is the image should move across the entire screen, randomly. This question might be asked in different way on stack but I'm not able to get it. Also the Image should fade whilst it is moving and when I touch/click the image it should give me a different view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:nil];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

-(void)fadeMe
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.2f animations:^{
        [view setAlpha:0.0f];
    }
     completion:^(BOOL finished){
         [view setAlpha:1.0f];
         isBackgroundrunning=NO;
     }];
}


-(void)onTimer{

    if(arc4random() % 10 == 1)
    {
        if (!isBackgroundrunning) {
            [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(fadeMe) withObject:nil];
            isBackgroundrunning=YES;
        }
    }
}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint pt=[touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGRect applebounds=[view frame];

    if (pt.x>applebounds.origin.x && pt.x<applebounds.origin.x+applebounds.size.width && pt.y>applebounds.origin.y && pt.y<applebounds.origin.y+applebounds.size.height) {

        [timer invalidate];

        applebounds.size.height*=2;
        applebounds.size.width*=2;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [view setFrame:applebounds];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];

            //perform your task here .....
        }];
    }
}
```